# Concatinating the entire row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I'm new to Pandas. I want to join entire row of strings to a paragraph, where each row comes up with only paragraph, instead for a number of columns. For example, if 10 columns and 5 rows are there in a Dataframe, I want the output to be 5 rows with a single column combining all 10 column's String Data to a single column. I actually need it to use Bag of Words/ TF-IDF to it for sentiment analysis. Need help to do it.

Comment: `df.astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1)`

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanx a ton.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a solution taken for row 1 may be

' '.join(str(x) for x in df.iloc(1,0:11))

if any better solution is there, it will be more helpful for me